plot isn't interactive in MNE
I'm using Pycharm with win 11 and Python 3.9. I was unable to generate a interactive EEG picture while additional code of plt.ion()
Do someone have the same issue
Thanks!
Solution of generating an interactive EEG image via MNE and Pycharm
